# Why does this kind of tail call of fibonacci run faster than pure tree recursion in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, programming-languages, fibonacci, tail-call-optimization

I'm trying to undestand tail call recursions. I convert pure tree-recursion fibonacci function:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

to a tail call version:

```
fib' 0 a = a
fib' 1 a = 1 + a
fib' n a = fib' (n-1) (fib' (n-2) a)
```

When I try these two versions, it seems that the second one is faster than the first tree-recusion even though I tried to use `seq` to force strict evaluation in the second one!

How does Haskell treat such tail calls inside GHC? Thanks!

Comment: I get two exactly the same run times for both `fib 30` and `fib' 30 0` in GHCi. so please add some supporting evidence for your claim. show how you call both, exactly.

Comment: Also, `fib' n a = fib' (n-1) (fib' (n-2) a)` is not tail recursive. The first call to `fib'` is in tail position, but the second is not.

Comment: @amalloy that's CPS and it usually is too considered to be tail (in Scheme and the like). the problem is really with the `1 + a` in the clause above it.

Comment: @WillNess I'm familiar with CPS, but I don't see how this code can be called CPS. Could you explain it to me? There is no explicit continuation, and `fib'` is called with the result of `fib'` directly, rather than giving one a lambda to continue with. Are you thinking of the second parameter to `fib'`, which is an integer, as sorta an "implicit continuation", where thunks are built up or something?

Comment: @amalloy exactly, yes. I mean because of the laziness, lambda is implied. I've seen this technique referred to that way [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641936/is-it-possible-to-do-quicksort-of-a-list-with-only-one-passing/9550430#comment12104234_7642083). (I think it is similar)

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for testing! I didn't use any strict testing tools, but just used: `:set +s`, and I tried `fib 30` and `fib' 30 0`, the total time is `3.77 secs` and `9.69 secs`.

Comment: @WillNess So If I use explicit CPS style, will they just get the same effect? And can I just think that using CPS(accumulating stack in heap) is sometimes more efficient than naive tree recursion?

Comment: @Comcx my times are exactly the same though for the two versions. I see no difference. anyway, both algorithms are exponential, so it doesn't really matter. :) but, to properly test something, make a standalone executable compiling with the -O2 flag, and test it at the shell prompt as `> myapp +RTS -s`.

Comment: also, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth. testing at least at two or three problem size points is a must. for an example why, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60378812/849891).

Comment: @WillNess Thank you very much! I will definitely improve my way of testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance of code tested at the GHCi interactive prompt can be quite misleading, so when benchmarking GHC code, it's a good idea to test it in a standalone executable compiled with `ghc -O2`.  Adding explicit type signatures and making sure `-Wall` doesn't report any warnings about "defaulting" types is helpful, too.  Otherwise, GHC may choose default numeric types that you didn't intend.  Finally, it's also a good idea to use the `criterion` benchmarking library, since it does a good job generating reliable and reproducible timing results.

Benchmarking your two `fib` versions this way with the program:

```
import Criterion.Main

fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

fib' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fib' 0 a = a
fib' 1 a = 1 + a
fib' n a = fib' (n-1) (fib' (n-2) a)

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain
  [ bench "fib" $ whnf fib 30
  , bench "fib'" $ whnf (fib' 30) 0
  ]
```

compiled with GHC 8.6.5 using `ghc -O2 -Wall Fib2.hs`, I get:

```
$ ./Fib2
benchmarking fib
time                 40.22 ms   (39.91 ms .. 40.45 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 39.91 ms   (39.51 ms .. 40.11 ms)
std dev              581.2 μs   (319.5 μs .. 906.9 μs)

benchmarking fib'
time                 38.88 ms   (38.69 ms .. 39.06 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 38.57 ms   (38.49 ms .. 38.67 ms)
std dev              188.7 μs   (139.6 μs .. 268.3 μs)
```

The difference here is quite small, but can be consistently reproduced.  The `fib'` version is about 3-5% faster than the `fib` version.

At this point, it's maybe worth pointing out that my type signatures used `Integer`.  This is also the default that GHC would have selected without explicit type signatures.  Replacing these with `Int` results in a massive performance improvement:

```
benchmarking fib
time                 4.877 ms   (4.850 ms .. 4.908 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 4.766 ms   (4.730 ms .. 4.808 ms)
std dev              122.2 μs   (98.16 μs .. 162.4 μs)

benchmarking fib'
time                 3.295 ms   (3.260 ms .. 3.332 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 3.218 ms   (3.202 ms .. 3.240 ms)
std dev              62.51 μs   (44.57 μs .. 88.39 μs)
```

That's why I recommend including explicit type signatures and making sure there are no warnings about default types.  Otherwise, you can spend a lot of time chasing tiny improvements when the real problem is a loop index that uses `Integer` when it could have used `Int`.  For this example, of course, there's the additional issue that the algorithm is all wrong, since the algorithm is quadratic, and a linear implementation is possible, like the usual "clever Haskell" solution:

```
-- fib'' 30 runs about 100 times faster than fib 30
fib'' :: Int -> Int
fib'' n = fibs !! n
  where fibs = scanl (+) 0 (1:fibs)
```

Anyway, let's switch back to `fib` and `fib'` using `Integer` for the rest of this answer...

The GHC compiler produces an intermediate form of a program called the STG (spineless, tagless, G-machine).  It's the highest-level representation that faithfully represents how the program will actually be run.  The best documentation of STG and how it's actually translated into heap allocations and stack frames is the paper [Making a fast curry: push/enter versus eval/apply for higher-order languages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/make-fast-curry-pushenter-vs-evalapply/).  When reading this paper, Figure 1 is the STG language (though the syntax differs from what GHC produces with `-ddump-stg`) and Figure 2's first and third panels show how STG is evaluated using an eval/apply approach (which matches current GHC-generated code).  There's also an older paper [Implementing lazy functional languages on stock hardware: the Spineless Tagless G-machine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/implementing-lazy-functional-languages-on-stock-hardware-the-spineless-tagless-g-machine/) that provides a lot more detail (probably too much), but it's a little out-of-date.

Anyway, to see the difference between `fib` and `fib'`, we can look at the generated STG using:

```
ghc -O2 -ddump-stg -dsuppress-all -fforce-recomp Fib2.hs
```

Taking the STG output and substantially cleaning it up to look more like "regular Haskell", I get the following definitions:

```
fib = \n ->                          fib' = \n a ->
  case (==) n 0 of                     case (==) n 0 of
    True -> 0                            True -> a;
    _ ->                                 _ ->
      case (==) n 1 of                     case (==) n 1 of
        True -> 1                            True -> (+) 1 a;                 -- (6)
        _ ->                                 _ ->
          case (-) n 2 of                      case (-) n 2 of
            n_minus_2 ->                         n_minus_2 ->
              case fib n_minus_2 of                case fib' n_minus_2 a of
                y ->                                 y ->
                  case (-) n 1 of                      case (-) n 1 of
                    n_minus_1 ->                         n_minus_1 ->
                      case fib n_minus_1 of                fib' n_minus_1 y   -- (14)
                        x -> (+) x y
```

Here, strictness analysis has already made the entire computation strict.  There are no thunks created here.  (In STG, only `let` blocks create thunks, and there are no `let` blocks in this STG.)  So, the (minimal) performance difference between these two implementations has nothing to do with strict versus lazy.

Ignoring the extra argument to `fib'`, note that these two implementations are essentially *structurally* identical except for the addition operation in line (6) in `fib'` and the case statement with addition operation in line (14) in `fib`.

To understand the difference between these two implementations, you first need to understand that a function call `f a b` is compiled to the pseudocode:

```
lbl_f:  load args a,b
        jump to f_entry
```

Note that all function calls, whether or not they are tail calls, are compiled to jumps like this.  When the code in `f_entry` completes, it will jump to whatever continuation frame is at the top of the stack, so if the caller wants to do something with the result of a function call, it should push a continuation frame before jumping.

For example, the block of code:

```
case f a b of
    True -> body1
    _    -> body2
```

wants to do something with the return value of `f a b`, so it compiles to the following (unoptimized) pseudocode:

```
        push 16-byte case continuation frame <lbl0,copy_of_arg1> onto the stack
lbl_f:  -- code block for f a b, as above:
        load args a,b
        jump to f_entry   -- f_entry will jump to lbl0 when done
lbl0:   restore copy_of_arg1, pop case continuation frame
        if return_value == True jump to lbl2 else lbl1
lbl1:   block for body1
lbl2:   block for body2
```

Knowing this, the difference in line (6) between the two implementations is the pseudocode:

```
-- True -> 1                              -- True -> (+) 1 a
load 1 as return value                    load args 1,a
jump to next continuation                 jump to "+"
                                          -- Note: "+" will jump to next contination
```

and the difference in line (14) between the two implementation is:

```
-- case fib n_minus_1 of ...              -- fib' n_minus_1 y
        push case continuation <lbl_a>    load args n_minus_1,y
        load arg n_minus_1                jump to fib'
        jump to fib
lbl_a:  pop case continuation
        load args returned_val,y
        jump to "+"
```

There's actually hardly any performance difference between these once they're optimized.  The assembly code generated for these blocks is:

```
-- True -> 1                              -- True -> (+) 1 a
                                          movq 16(%rbp),%rsi
movl $lvl_r83q_closure+1,%ebx             movl $lvl_r83q_closure+1,%r14d
addq $16,%rbp                             addq $24,%rbp
jmp *(%rbp)                               jmp plusInteger_info

-- case fib n_minus_1 of ...              -- fib' n_minus_1 y
movq $block_c89A_info,(%rbp)              movq 8(%rbp),%rax
movq %rbx,%r14                            addq $16,%rbp
jmp fib_info                              movq %rax,%rsi
movq 8(%rbp),%rsi                         movq %rbx,%r14
movq %rbx,%r14                            // fall through to start of fib'
addq $16,%rbp
jmp plusInteger_info
```

The difference here is a few instructions.  A few more instructions are saved because the fall-through in `fib' n_minus_1 y` skips the overhead of a stack size check.

In the version using `Int`, the additions and comparisons are all single instructions, and the difference between the two assemblies is -- by my count -- five instructions out of about 30 instructions total.  Because of the tight loop, that's enough to account for the 33% performance difference.

So, the bottom line is that there's no fundamental structural reason that `fib'` is faster than `fib`, and the small performance improvement comes down to micro-optimizations on the order of a handful of instructions that the tail call allows.

In other situations, reorganizing a function to introduce a tail call like this may or may not improve performance.  This situation was probably unusual in that the reorganization of the function had very limited effect on the STG and so the net improvement of a few instructions wasn't swamped by other factors.